# Specifying STL Map key with 3 components

Tags: c++, stl

I am fairly new to STL. So pardon me if the question is naive.

I have a pair like this that is used as a key to a map.

`typedef pair <int, int> KeyPair;`

My map is as shown below

`typedef map <KeyPair, uint32> NvInfoMap;`

**Now I want to introduce a new integer into the Key part of the map.**

Which is the easiest way to do this?

Do I have to make another pair that will take the existing pair as its latter part?

Please note that I am on a restricted environment where boost library is not available.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Consider using a [`std::tuple`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple) instead of a pair. `typedef tuple<int, int, int> KeyType;`

Comment: @SeanCline : Tuple is not supported. Decided to use a nested pair.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your restrictions allow C++11, then

```
typedef std::tuple<int, int, int> KeyTriple;
```

Otherwise, you could define your own type

```
struct KeyTriple {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};
```

with an ordering to allow it to be used as a key

```
bool operator<(KeyTriple const & lhs, KeyTriple const & rhs) {
    if (lhs.a < rhs.a) return true;
    if (rhs.a < lhs.a) return false;
    if (lhs.b < rhs.b) return true;
    if (rhs.b < lhs.b) return false;
    if (lhs.c < rhs.c) return true;
    return false;

    // Alternatively, if you can use C++11 but don't want a tuple for a key
    return std::tie(lhs.a, lhs.b, lhs.c) < std::tie(rhs.a, rhs.b, rhs.c);
}
```

or, as you suggest, you could use a nested pair

```
typedef std::pair<int, std::pair<int, int>>;
```

with the advantage that it defines the necessary comparison operator for you, but the disadvantage that creating one and accessing its elements is a bit of a faff.

Comment: Thanks. Honestly, I don't know whether I could use C++ 11. I will check this now. This is for a MIPS based embedded target.

Comment: That `operator<` is awfully long. It could be written as `return tie(lhs.a, lhs.b, lhs.c) < tie(rhs.a, rhs.b, rhs.c);`

Comment: @SeanCline: That requires C++11, in which case you'd probably use `tuple` anyway. (I guess you could embed an array rather than three variables, and use `lexicographical_compare`, if you want to avoid writing this somewhat error-prone code).

Comment: @MikeSeymour, Compilers with support for `TR1` are pretty commonplace. I had forgotten it was new to the standard.